# sap.m.TablePersoDialog class throws an error (which is a bug, I think?)

Tags: uitableview, sapui5

I am using  sap.m.TablePersoDialog for my application, which basically builds a column selection dialog for user. Everytime I click on the button to call that dialog, I am getting the below error. My application works on 1.60.3 version.

The error takes me to the TablePersoController.dbg class which you can see the property 'grouping' is exist and set to false. But actually, in the class, the property is set to name as 'hasGrouping'.  https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.60.3/#/api/sap.m.TablePersoController
[image]

**ERROR: Assertion failed: ManagedObject.apply: encountered unknown setting 'grouping' for class 'sap.m.TablePersoDialog' (value:'false')**

Comment: It has a `setHasGrouping` method that you can use to switch the grouping on and off.

Comment: You are right, but I am not doing anthing with 'grouping' property. Why would I need to setHasGrouping? It is already set to false by default. The error happening because of the name of the property has not been changed in the debugger class.

Comment: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/eb71e101a82424d6e2a9f2f665ef92605b9847b6#diff-dc9203f19c1bddb93b4843381ba887ca

Comment: I craeted an incident for you. The control is sap/ui/table/TablePersoController and not sap/m/TablePersoController. If you can switch to sap/m the issue should be gone. Otherwise you have to wait for them to release a new 1.60 patch

Comment: Thank you for your kind interest, I just wanted to let the responsibles know :) thanks again for your action!